# Deleting rows in pandas dataframe where label count > 2

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, which looks like this:

```
**ReviewerID**          **ReviewText**        **Categories**       **ProductId**

    1212                   good product         Mobile               14444425
    1233                   will buy again       drugs                324532
    5432                   not recomended       Mobile               789654123
```

I want to delete all rows whose categories value does not appear atleast twice.
The resultant dataframe should look like this:

```
**ReviewerID**       **ReviewText**        **Categories**       **ProductId**

    1212                   good product         Mobile               14444425
    5432                   not recomended       Mobile               789654123
```

I'm new to python and pandas, help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
print df.groupby('Categories').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
   ReviewerID      ReviewText Categories  ProductId
0        1212    good product     Mobile   14444425
2        5432  not recomended     Mobile  789654123
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration).